# How can I write SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need a request that displays the name and surname of the clients with the smallest credit limit - among married women who do not live in Japan, Brazil or Italy.

Diagram:

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask]. What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images, in questions.

Answer (score 0):

This will Give all the people not in 'Japan', 'Brazil' or 'Italy') ,

```
Select C.Cust_first_name,C.Cust_Last_name from Customers C 
          Inner Join Countries C1
               on C.Country_Id=C1.Country_Id 
        Where C1.Country_Name Not in('Japan', 'Brazil' or 'Italy') 
        and 
    C.Cust_Credit_Limit=(Select Min(Cust_Credit_Limit) From from Customers C)
```

If we Convert The Question to Code that will be the above code,
The Script would return the name and last name of person not in ('Japan', 'Brazil' or 'Italy') And has the lowest salary In the entire customer Base.

Comment: also all necessary rows exist in Customers table: marital status -cust_marital_status, gender - cust_gender,  country - country_id

Answer (score 0):

select top 1 * from Customers C

Inner Join

(
select MIn(cust_credit_limit) from Customers C1

Inner Join Countries CT on C1.Country_id = C1.Country_id

where CT.Country_Name  Not in ('Japan', 'Brazil','Italy')

)
 C2 on C2.cust_credit_limit = C.cust_credit_limit